# Doctrine2 case-sensitive query

Tags: doctrine-orm, case-sensitive

for some reason I need to query 'case-sensitive' in MySql + doctrine 2. Is it possible?

neither

```
$em->find('UserEn', 'Bob')
```

nor

```
$q = $this->em->createQuery('select u from UserEn u where u.name = :name');
$q->setParameter('name', 'Bob');
$result = $q->getResult();
```

is working. Any idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe you are using a MySQL collation ending with "_ci", like "utf8_general_ci". "ci" stands for "case insensitive". 
If this is the case, it is not a Doctrine issue, but a MySQL issue.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

"The default character set and collation are latin1 and latin1_swedish_ci, so nonbinary string comparisons are case insensitive by default."

Answer (score 3):

For those that are unable to change their database collation, you can use the `BINARY` operator in order to force case sensitivity on the criteria.

> The BINARY operator casts the string following it to a binary string.
>   This is an easy way to force a comparison to be done byte by byte
>   rather than character by character. BINARY also causes trailing spaces
>   to be significant.

See [MySQL BINARY Operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-binary-op.html) for more details.

To enable the `BINARY` operator in Doctrine DQLs, you can install the [Doctrine Extensions library](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions).
Or create your own Binary String Function like so.

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode,
    Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

class Binary extends FunctionNode
{
    private $stringPrimary;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->stringPrimary = $parser->StringPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'BINARY('.$sqlWalker->walkSimpleArithmeticExpression($this->stringPrimary).')';
    }
}
```

Next you'll need to register the `binary` string function with your doctrine configuration. You can do so in your configuration settings or add it as needed like so.

```php
$em->getConfiguration()->addCustomStringFunction('binary', 'DoctrineExtensions\\Query\\Mysql\\Binary');
```

Then you will be able to use the `binary(...)` function in your DQL like so.

```php
$q = $em->createQuery('select u from UserEn u where binary(u.name) = :name');
echo $q->getSQL();
/* SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE BINARY(u0_.name) = ? */
```

To add the `binary` string function using the Symfony Framework, in your `config.yml` file change the `doctrine.orm.entity_managers.%entity_manager%.dql` setting like so.

```
doctrine:
    orm:
      #...
      entity_managers:
          #...
          default:
              #...
              dql:
                  #...
                  string_functions:
                      #...
                      binary: 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Binary'
```

See [Symfony Doctrine Configuration Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

It's not Doctrine issue you have to change table collation to binary then case sensitive would work.
Do alter table and change this
**CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci**
to this
**CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin**