# Symfony 2 findBy order result case insensitive

Tags: jquery, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-query

```
$this->get('bundle_name.entity_name.service')->findBy(array(), array('name' => 'ASC'));
```

This gives the following result when displaying the names:
A
B
C
b

How can I order the result case insensitive? So that the result would be like this when displaying the names:
A 
b 
B 
C

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doctrine2 case-sensitive query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129571/doctrine2-case-sensitive-query)

Answer (score 0):

Your service looks like a repository. But your data layout doesn't have to do that.

So your best solution is to overide your findBy method and add a `natcasesort()` to reorder your entities.

[Sort array items in PHP so that it is not case sensitive to letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763936/sort-array-items-in-php-so-that-it-is-not-case-sensitive-to-letters)