# TYPO3 queryBuilder: How to work with BINARY in where() clause?

Tags: typo3, builder, connection-pool

I just have a short question.

There's no description in the following API overview of TYPO3 how to use a "BINARY" in where() clause: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/QueryBuilder/Index.html#expr

What I want to achieve? this one:

```
WEHRE BINARY `buyer_code` = "f#F67d";
```

Actually I can only do the following:

```
->where(
  $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('buyer_code', 'f#F67d')
);
```

But in this case I don't get a satisfying result for myself because I need case-sensitive here :-)

An another buyer_code exists "f#F67**D**" (the last char is uppercase) but I do need to look for the other one.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: do you have to do it on the repository or is there the option to make the request via QueryBuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since TYPO3 is using Doctrine API here, you could try to do

```
->where('BINARY `buyer_code` = ' . $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('f#F67d'))
```

Please keep in mind, that this query now only works for database backends, supporting the BINARY keyword!

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [Doctrine2 case-sensitive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129571/doctrine2-case-sensitive-query) The thread is a bit older, but seems to cover background and solution for your problem.

Comment: Thank you also for your qualified answer.