# TYPO3: Case sensitive search with BINARY in Doctrine where clause

Tags: php, doctrine, typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm currently migrating an old TYPO3 application from `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']` to Doctrine.

In the old application there was a case sensitive search with the BINARY operator:

```php
$whereClause = 'BINARY myfieldname LIKE "%' . $query . '%"';
```

I tried to migrate it like this:

```php
$queryBuilder->expr()->like('BINARY myfieldname', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('%' . $queryBuilder->escapeLikeWildcards($query) . '%'))
```

Another attempt was like this:

```php
$queryBuilder->expr()->like('BINARY `myfieldname`', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('%' . $queryBuilder->escapeLikeWildcards($query) . '%'))
```

This always ends up with an error message:
`` Unknown column 'BINARY `label`' in 'where clause' ``

Unfortunately there is no way to change anything at the MySQL server settings.

I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58688692/typo3-querybuilder-how-to-work-with-binary-in-where-clause) but it didn't help me.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you try the `$queryBuilder->add()` parameter? With it you can append or replace query parts.

Comment: Thx for the hint, that worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me (thx to the hint of Thomas):

```php
$whereClause = $queryBuilder->expr()->like(
  'label',
  $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('%' . $queryBuilder->escapeLikeWildcards($query) . '%')
);
$whereClause = 'BINARY ' . $whereClause;
$queryBuilder->add('where', $whereClause);
```